# How to move/rename object with overwritting in Zope?

Tags: plone, zope, plone-4.x

I'm trying to move object (i.e. image file) from one folder to another one and then rename it  - overwrite with existing object (i.e. updating file).

I'm doing it in `Zope` (I use `Plone 4.2`) in the following way:

```py
from zope.component.hooks import getSite
from zope.traversing.api import traverse

site = getSite()
src = traverse(site, "preview/")
dst = traverse(site, "images/")
source = src.manage_cutObjects(ids=[previewName])
dst.manage_pasteObjects(source)
dst.manage_delObjects(ids=[existingName])
```

That piece of code does what it should do, it moves the object from one folder to another, then, as `manage_renameObject` procedure doesn't allow overwritting I delete the existing object which will be replaced. But if I add this line of code to achieve the final goal:

```py
dst.manage_renameObject(previewName, existingName)
```

the exception is thrown, that ID provided by `existingName` is invalid (because the object with such ID already exists and no matter that I have deleted it before).

It looks like I need some *commit* or *update* to finalize *object moving* (or *wait* etc) but I can't find anything about that.

**UPDATE**

I forget to add: all changes (object moving, object deletion) before exception in `manage_renameObject` was thrown weren't applied. Now, with `transaction.commit()` (as proposed by [lewicki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358869/how-to-move-rename-object-with-overwritting-in-zope/18360851#18360851)) the changes are applied but exception still occurs. Procedure `transaction.savepoint()` didn't help much, the exception was still thrown and changes weren't applied.

**RESOLVED**

I was confused initially by the error message:

```html
<CENTER>
('Empty or invalid id specified', u'27')
</CENTER>
```

When I tried to reproduce the issue in the `ZMI` I got:

```html
<CENTER>
The id "27" is invalid - it is already in use.
</CENTER>
```

and I realized that I needed to look into the code.
I dig into the installed `Plone` code and then located what I looked for in `eggs/Zope2-2.13.18-py2.7.egg/OFS/ObjectManager.py` module, in `checkValidId()` procedure.. There was the root of all my problems:

```py
if not id or not isinstance(id, str):
    if isinstance(id, unicode):
        id = escape(id)
    raise BadRequest, ('Empty or invalid id specified', id)
```

so, I strict object names (IDs) to **`str`** type and it all became working...

Neither `commit()` nor `savepoint()` even was needed (but initially when I was figuring out the issue and observing in `ZMI` that my files was neither moved nor deleted that was confused me a lot).

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I'm confused. You are *cutting* the *new* name? That makes no sense.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro, yes I agree, in my source code I use `previewName` and `finalName`, so I've updated the question.

Comment: OK, so the problem is that you get an error when renaming an object to "foo", because "foo" already exists, even though you have deleted "foo"?

Comment: @Lennart Regebro, exactly!

Comment: I think you should clarify your question because that's far from obvious. Also add the actual code you are using with the actual traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It's `dst.manage_renameObject(oldid, newid)`. This should work

[Documentation](http://developer.plone.org/content/rename.html)

Comment: That is what the OP is **doing**, except his variables are called `newName` and `existingName`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, but he is using newName for the old id, and existingName for the new id. You have to be drunk to do that. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right - commit may be requred. I had a similar problem and it was solved that way:

```
from zope.component.hooks import getSite
from zope.traversing.api import traverse
import transaction

site = getSite()
src = traverse(site, "preview/")
dst = traverse(site, "images/")
source = src.manage_cutObjects(ids=[newName])
dst.manage_pasteObjects(source)
dst.manage_delObjects(ids=[existingName])
transaction.commit()
```

Now I think that

```
transaction.savepoint()
```

should be enough but you have to check on your own.

Comment: Don't `commit()`; use `transaction.savepoint(optimistic=True)` to create a savepoint.